# How to remove dates in a Gantt chart in VISIO 2010

Tags: date, visio, gantt-chart

I have created a Gantt chart in VISIO 2010. I realized that my start dates are misleading since I do not know for sure when exactly I am going to start this new project, but I am happy with my time estimations. How can I remove the start date and end date from my Gantt chart but keep the "Duration"? I would like to see my chart with columns named Week 1, week 2, week 3 (or something similar) rather than specific dates... Is this possible in VISIO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `begin` and `end` dates are required in Visio Gantt template. You could only hide these columns